# Properly sized `\cite` in math superscript

Tags: math-mode, citing, superscripts

I would like to cite a reference as a superscript of a mathematical symbol, like so:

```
$x^{\cite{nicebook}}$
```

When I do that, though, the citation symbol is poorly displayed, with e.g., the brackets correctly sized but the number itself wrongly sized. A full example is below:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor={blue}}

\begin{document}

$x^{\cite{nicebook}}$

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \bibitem{nicebook} A nice book
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

with output:

---

[image]

---

But the fontsize of `1` in the `[1]`-superscript is too large: is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? This would be rather annoying to read.

Comment: It's needed to separate a conventional definition (assigned a superscript) in the literature from our definition (not assigned a superscript) and is used very infrequently (in practice, twice). In practice, please disregard whether this is subjectively a good idea: it has a specific use-case for me.

Comment: if you really must do this, amsmath package and `^{\text{\cite{aaa}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wonderful: that exactly did the trick: thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must do this, `amsmath` package and `^{\text{\cite{aaa}}}`